# How do you count checked checkboxes, excluding the header, in an asp.net gridview using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm currently counting all the checked checkboxes in an asp.net gridview using:

```
$('#cphMain_gdvSalesOrder').delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', function() {
    var count = $('#cphMain_gdvSalesOrder').find('input:checkbox:checked').length;
```

Whereas I need to count all the checkboxes that are checked apart from the one in the header.

Any ideas would be great, thanks

Korv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a "flag" CSS Class to the check-boxes in the grid which is not assigned to the check-box in the header. This way you can filter out the header check-box as part of your selector based on CSS Class.

`:not(.headerCheckBox)`

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. It also somehow fixes the problem I was having using the header checkbox as an indicator as well as a activator.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0; 
var grid = document.getElementById("<%=grdProductImage.ClientID%>"); 
var chk = grid.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) 
{ 
   if (chk[i].checked && chk[i].id.indexOf("chkAll") == -1) { 
        count = count + 1; 
   } 
}
```